# Vectors and $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For vectors $a$ $b$ and $c$ belong to $\mathbb{R}^n$, if $a·b=a·c$, then $b=c$?

Comment: Are you asking the question: "If $a\cdot b=a\cdot c$, then does $b=c$?" Or are you asking: "If $a\cdot b=a\cdot c$ for all $a\in\mathbb R^n$, then does $b=c$?"

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a perfectly clear question.

Comment: The downvote is because it does not show any effort on OP's part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you restricted your question, I'm changing my answer.

No. Consider $a = (1,0,\ldots,0), b = (0,1,\ldots,0)$ and $c=(0,-1,\ldots,0)$. Then $a \cdot b = a \cdot c = 0$ but $b \neq c$.

This is for **given** $a$. If this holds **for all** $a$ then it is true.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{k=1}^n a_nb_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_nc_n \implies \sum_{k=1}^n a_k(b_k - c_k)$

Extracting a term from the sum gives us the equality:

$(b_1 - c_1) = -[\sum_{k=2}^n(b_k-c_k)]/c_1$, with $ a_k,b_k,c_k \in \mathbb{R}$

Which implies that the summation can take on nonzero values.